# scikit-learn: SVM giving me zero error, but can't predict

Tags: python, svm, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

I am working on a support vector machine, using sci-kit learn in Python.

I have trained the model, used GridSearch and cross-validation to find the optimal parameters, and have 
evaluated the best model on a 15% holdout set.

The confusion matrix at the end says I have 0 misclassifications.
Later the model gave me incorrect predictions when I give it a handwritten digit (I haven't included the code for this, to keep this question respectfully short).

Because the SVM has zero error and further, later on it can't predict correctly, I have built this SVM incorrectly.

My question is this:

*Am I right to suspect I used Cross Validation along with GridSearch somehow incorrectly?  Or have I given GridSearch parameters that are somehow ridiculous, and are giving me false results?*

Thanks for your time and effort for reading this far.

---

**STEP 1: split the data set into 85%/15% using the train_test_split function**

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test =
cross_validation.train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.15,
random_state=0)
```

**STEP 2: apply the GridSearchCV function to the training set to tune the classifier**

```
C_range = 10.0 ** np.arange(-2, 9)
gamma_range = 10.0 ** np.arange(-5, 4)
param_grid = dict(gamma=gamma_range, C=C_range)
cv = StratifiedKFold(y=y, n_folds=3)

grid = GridSearchCV(SVC(), param_grid=param_grid, cv=cv)
grid.fit(X, y)

print("The best classifier is: ", grid.best_estimator_)
```

**The output is here:**

```
('The best classifier is: ', SVC(C=10.0, cache_size=200,
class_weight=None, coef0=0.0, degree=3,
 gamma=0.0001, kernel='rbf', max_iter=-1, probability=False,
 random_state=None, shrinking=True, tol=0.001, verbose=False))
```

**STEP 3: Finally, evaluate the tuned classifier on the remaining 15%
hold-out set.**

```
clf = svm.SVC(C=10.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0, degree=3,
  gamma=0.001, kernel='rbf', max_iter=-1, probability=False,
  random_state=None, shrinking=True, tol=0.001, verbose=False)

clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

clf.score(X_test, y_test)
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
```

**The output is here:**

```
precision recall f1-score support

      -1.0       1.00      1.00      1.00         6
       1.0       1.00      1.00      1.00        30

avg / total       1.00      1.00      1.00        36

Confusion Matrix:
[[ 6  0]
[ 0 30]]
```

Comment: Have you tried evaluating it with more test samples? If the test sample that you mentioned is not from training and hold-out set, I think this is a probable outcome and not an error of your code. Zero error on hold-out set does not guarantee zero error on real test set. On the other hand, the hold-out set error might be an over-optimistic estimate of test error, as GridSearchCV has seen all the X and y, including the hold-outs.

Comment: I have used cv = StratifiedKFold(y=y, n_folds=3), which is 3-fold cross validation done over 85% of the data...so I believe the 15% of the data that serves as the test set has never been seen by the grid search.
Meanwhile, the sample used to predict (which didn't work) has never been seen before by the SVM and lives in a different file.  Unfortunately I just have one of these.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, is ``X, y`` 100% of the data and ``X_train, y_train`` 85% of the data?

Comment: But then ``grid.fit(X, y)`` means the ``GridSearchCV`` has seen all the data, including the 15% hold out data which is in ``X_test, y_test``. I thought it should be something like ``grid.fit(X_train, y_train)``, so that the hold-out data is really held out.

Comment: I absolutely love your idea.  However, when I attempt this `grid.fit(X_train, y_train)` I get `IndexError: index 199 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 199`.  Hummmm...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46183/discussion-between-matt-obrien-and-ys-l)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have too few data in your test set (only 6 samples for one of the classes) to be confident in the predictive accuracy of your model. I would recommend labeling at least 150 samples per classes and keep 50 samples in the held out test to compute the evaluation metrics.

Edit: also have a look at the new sample that it fails to predict: are the feature values in the same range (e.g [0, 255] instead of [0, 1] or [-1, 1] for the digits from training and test sets)? does the new digit "looks" like other digits from your test set when you plot them using matplotlib for instance?

Comment: Thanks for both of these simple, practical and valuable insights!  

My original data set has 235 observations.  Since this is apparently too few, can I work around it using K-fold Cross validation, or could you please recommend a good resource that describes how to work around this limitation in the best possible way?  Thanks!

Comment: I've accepted the answer and continued the issue here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21415934/using-sci-kit-learn-how-do-i-learn-a-svm-over-a-small-data-set